# Why can't I plot Log[Gamma[x]] for x > 170?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

For some reason I can't plot `Log[Gamma[x]]` for values of `x` larger than approximately 170:

```
Plot[Log[Gamma[x]], {x, 130, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It works perfectly well with `ListPlot` (that is, values of this function are defined for `x>170`:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Log[Gamma[x]]}, {x, 130, 200}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

as well as with the internally combined `LogGamma`:

```
Plot[LogGamma[x], {x, 130, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It is also not a problem with the `PlotRange`. Even if I set the range manually, it will still not plot any points for `x>170`. What is wrong here?

Comment: There seems to be a discontinuity in `s[x]`. Because when I tried with the  additional attribute `Exclusions->None`, it worked.

Comment: That's very interesting indeed. Another proof that it can plot the data with normal working precision.

Comment: Works fine for me in M9, 10.3, and M11.1. What version are you using? Or maybe it's an OS thing? Are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit operating system?

Comment: Version 11.0.1 on Linux, 64 bit. But you are right, I don't have the problem on version 10.4.1

Comment: This is a new bug (regression) in 11. I have reported this to Wolfram support a few months ago.  As Carl says, the bug is not present in previous versions and will be fixed in the next one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug specific to version 11.0.

As noted in the comments by @AnjanKumar, the bug seems to be related to exclusion detection. The simple workaround is turning it off:

```
Plot[Log[Gamma[x]], {x, 130, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Exclusions -> None (* disable exclusions *)
]
```

Answer (score 8):

`Plot` uses machine precision numbers, but `Gamma[x]` becomes larger than the largest number that can be represented with machine numbers right about $x=170$:

```
FindRoot[LogGamma[x] == Log@$MaxMachineNumber, {x, 160}]

(* Out: {x -> 171.624} *)
```

I suspect that to be part of the difficulty. However, something else is going on here. Compare the result above to the following, where `Log[Gamma[x]]` is "hidden" behind `NumericQ`, and the plot works fine (!):

```
lg[x_?NumericQ] := Log[Gamma[x]]
Plot[lg[x], {x, 165., 200.}]
```

[image: masked log gamma]

Also, in comments Anjan noted that adding `Exclusions -> None` makes the plot work fine. I don't know how exclusions are handled inside plot, but I wonder if the fact that the value of the function exceeds `$MaxMachineNumber` triggers the exclusion handling and prevents its further plotting. A more authoritative viewpoint on this issue would be welcome.

---

Notice that other functions gracefully increase the evaluation precision when tasked to evaluate `Log@Gamma`, but don't need to do so when evaluating `LogGamma`:

```
Precision /@ Table[Log@Gamma[x], {x, 165., 185., 5}]
(* Out: {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, 15.9546, 15.9546, 15.9546} *)

Precision /@ Table[LogGamma[x], {x, 160., 200., 5}]
(* Out:  {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, 
          MachinePrecision} *)
```

Comment: But why is it that I can evaluate it just fine in a `Table` and then `ListPlot` the result?

Comment: @Felix `Table` internally switches to arbitrary precision and increases it appropriately to be able to represent the result. See the result of `Precision /@ Table[Log@Gamma[x], {x, 160., 210.}]`.

Comment: But in contrast to your example, where with `f[x_] := Sin[x^x]` I can't evaluate `f[150.]`, here `Log[Gamma[200.5]]` evaluates just fine. Also, I can generate the table with floating point numbers.

Comment: I am not convinced by this magical increase of precision. For instance, `Precision[Log@Gamma[1000000.]]=15.9546`. Shouldn't such a large number require much more precision? Also, why does Anjan's suggestion work if it is a working precision issue?

Comment: @Felix 1) `Precision[Log@Gamma[1000000.]]=15.9546` is the precision of the result, not of the intermediate numbers necessary to arrive at that result. The existence of [`$MaxExtraPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MaxExtraPrecision.html) hints at the fact that higher arbitrary precision can be used internally to arrive at a result. 2) I agree; there is something funny connected with `Plot` that I haven't been able to pinpoint yet.