# Having problems with NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I have data points — denoted by `Fk`— covering quite a large range $(1,\,10^{1010})$. I plotted them with `ListLogPlot`. Then I tried to fit the data points using `NonlinearModelFit`, and now I have two problems:

1. Fitting the data points

   ```
   fit = NonlinearModelFit[Fk[300], a*k^(B*k), {a, B}, k]
   ```

   gives `1 k^1` for the fitted model.

   However, fitting the data points with:

   ```
   fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[Fk[300], a*k^(b*c*k), {a, b, c}, k]
   ```

   gives the fitted model `140.714 k^1.16997 k` which I completely do not unterstand. I mean why should the output change upon inserting the variable $c$, which could also be combined with $b$ such that say $b\,c= B$ and `fit` should be equal to `fit2`.
2. If I now plot the data `Fk` vs. `k` together with the fitted model, the fitted curve ends at some value of $k \approx 120$, and I do not unterstand why. My code for this is

   ```
   Show[{ListLogPlot[Fk[300], PlotStyle -> Red], LogPlot[fit2[k], {k, 0, 300}]}]
   ```

[image: plot]

Red dots = data points; blue line = fitted curve

Comment: Thanks, is it now ok?

Comment: Yes, I will delete my comment.

Comment: Can you provide us with your points? (Btw it makes no sense to fit `b*c` since they're directly correlated into each other.)

Comment: For the fact that the plot stops at a value around k=120, that may be because your function is hitting the upper limit of machine-precision numbers. See [(105774)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105774). Try increasing the `WorkingPrecision` for your `Plot` function.

Comment: Non-linear fitting rarely plug-and-play. Two things I would recommend: (i) Find a good initial guess for the parameters. E.g., `a=Fk[0]`. (ii) If the fit is 1% off at `k=300` the absolute error is $10^{800}$ times larger than a 1000% error at `k=50`. That is, you probably want to specify weights to be some function of `Fk`. Finally, plotting works with `Exclusions -> None`, see [this bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137666/why-cant-i-plot-loggammax-for-x-170/137691#137691).

Comment: You almost certainly want to fit the log of `Fk[300]`:  `NonlinearModelFit[Log[Fk[300]], Log[a] + B k  Log[k], {a, B}, k]`.  Then you want to check the residuals to see if the assumption of a constant variance makes sense.

Comment: The data points are given by:  Fk[n_] = LinearSolve[
  Table[PadRight[Table[StirlingS2[k, m], {m, k}], n], {k, 1, n}], 
  Table[BellB[k]^2, {k, 1, n}]]

Comment: The problem however still is that if I just use NonlinearModelFit to fit these data with the model: fit= NonlinearModelFit[Fk[300], a*x^(b*x), {a, b}, x] the Output is: FittedModel[1.k^(1.k)] which is obviously wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "still ... wrong"? Did you apply any of the suggestions above? The result is simply indicative for a failure to find a fit, so the initial parameters (1,1) are returned.

Comment: Yes, I tried to Increase the WorkingPrecision and finding out how to use an initial guess for the Parameters. Actually I really just started using mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

You want to fit the log of `Fk[300]` and add in some constraints for the parameters.

```
Fk[n_] := LinearSolve[
   Table[PadRight[Table[StirlingS2[k, m], {m, k}], n], {k, 1, n}], 
   Table[BellB[k]^2, {k, 1, n}]];
data = Transpose[{Range[1, 300], Log[Fk[300]]}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a] + b k Log[k], a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b}, k];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 74145.49180618675`,b -> 1.1879871492270795`} *)
```

But this doesn't provide a great fit.  (Or rather if you add in a few more terms, you can predict a whole lot better.  But that's not a *Mathematica* issue.)

```
ListLogPlot[{Fk[300], Exp[nlm["PredictedResponse"]]}]
```

[image: Fit using logs]

Here is a "close-up" of the lack of fit showing the residual associated with the values of `k`:
[image: Residuals vs k]

Comment: Hi Jim. Thanks for your answer. I now used your NonlinearModelFit however I got  a different a and b: {a -> 1.70003*10^-6, b -> 1.20435}

Comment: And yes, you are right it is not the best fit. I will try to make it better, but what I am looking for is just an asymptotic behaviour of the Fk, thus from the fit I already kind of see what to expect.

Comment: Using `loga` as the parameter rather than `a` in `Log[a]` gives a number much closer to yours and (maybe more importantly) gives a smaller error variance.  However, if your objective is to estimate asymptotic behaviour and you're not so interested in small values of `k`, then that probably doesn't help much.

Comment: Yeah I realized that even for getting just an asymptotic behaviour my fit was far too bad, thus I changed the model to ak^(bk^c). Now the fit is much better and the residuals pretty small. Thanks again for your answer.